# Convention for a client-side (Flash) deep link path separator?

Tags: flash, url, actionscript, deep-linking, swfaddress

I see examples in the SWFAddress documentation, but it's not clear what the convention should be for a multi-level path. Do their examples intend to suggest that the path separator should be a hyphen?

Why not like this?

```
http://example.com/#/deep/link/path
```

Comment: I note this which I just found in RFC3986 §3.5: “The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") are allowed to represent data within the fragment identifier.  Beware that some older, erroneous implementations may not handle this data correctly when it is used as the base URI for relative references (Section 5.1).”

I say “Damn the ‘older, erroneous implementations’!” and unless someone can point me to a current “erroneous implementation” of a major browser or some other practical point, I’m going to use this convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the general setup of swfAddress is to work with the / and ? identifiers, as functions like getPath and getParameters looking specifically for a / or ? identified string.

Comment: Ah, yes. And the existence of SWFAddress.getPathNames() confirms that. Thanks!